# Change event binding's function called on page load

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a `select` and I am binding the `change` event on it so upon changes my function will fire.

The thing is: when my page loads it fires this function, which I don't want to happen. I only want it to fire when the user actually changes the value of the dropdown.

My select dropdown:

```html
<select data-bind="options: Main.Items, 
                   optionsText: 'Name', 
                   value: Main.SelectedItems, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Please Select', 
                   event: { change: function(data,event) { ItemClick(null) }}">
</select>
```

If anyone knows why it is firing on load, as well as how I can sort this out, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: A guess: you set / change the content of `Main.SelectedItems` after load in your viewmodel, which triggers the change event.

Comment: I would try to avoid using events where possible with knockout - part of what it helps with is separating your code from your view.  Instead, you could [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to `Main.SelectedItems` and watch for changes there instead, probably with a lot more control over what happens when the page loads.

Comment: Above two comments are spot on. I had already posted an answer similar to @JamesThorpe's suggestion before spotting the comments. I've added a section to my answer to address the first comment as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a red flag when using Knockout. Use either [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) or [subscriptions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to trigger logic upon value changes. E.g.:

```js
var MainViewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.Items = [{Name: 'apple'}, {Name: 'orange'}];
  self.SelectedItems = ko.observable();
  
  function ItemClick(newValue) {
    alert(ko.toJSON(newValue));
  }
  
  self.SelectedItems.subscribe(ItemClick);
}

ko.applyBindings({ Main: new MainViewModel() });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: Main.Items, 
                   optionsText: 'Name',
                   value: Main.SelectedItems,
                   optionsCaption: 'Please Select'"></select>
```

Make sure you set `SelectedItems` as above, or explicitly to `undefined`. That is, if you were to initialize with `null`, the UI would use the `optionsCaption` to immediately set it to `undefined` again, triggering the subscription.

PS. Your View suggests multiple items can be selected (since the property's pluralized), if so you'd need the `multiple` attribute on your `selecte` as well as a combination of an `observableArray` for `SelectedItems` and [the `selectedOptions` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html).

PPS. The code you posted does not behave the way your actual code does. That is, in the following snippet, you can see the `event` bound `ItemClick` function is not triggered until first time you change the drop down.

```js
function ItemClick(x) {
  alert(x);
}

var MainViewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.Items = [{Name: 'apple'}, {Name: 'orange'}];
  self.SelectedItems = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings({ Main: new MainViewModel() });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: Main.Items, 
                   optionsText: 'Name', 
                   value: Main.SelectedItems, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Please Select', 
                   event: { change: function(data,event) { ItemClick(null) }}"></select>
```